# Python request behaviour

Tags: python, request, http-status-code-200

I want to check if a website exists. I use the request module to make a get request and check the status code after the request was made.

```
    def check_website_exist(self, url):
        result = True
        request = requests.get("http://"+url)
        print(request.status_code)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            output.info("website found!")
            return result
        else:
            output.error("website not found!")
            result = False
            return result
```

When I make a request for the site '*www.isdfugpdohsiughsdopiughdsfoiguf.com*' I get the status code 200, even though the site doesn't exists. Why do I get a 200 status code, but the website doesn't exist?

Comment: Can't reproduce: ```requests.get('http://www.isdfugpdohsiughsdopiughdsfoiguf.com')``` raises ```ConnectionError```. Try opening this url in your browser. Also you can examine ```request.content```.

Comment: When I open the url in my browser it doesn't find the site. But I get the same result with urllib2.urlopen. I always get, that the site was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it. you are not catching the possible errors.

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
try:
    url = "http://www.isdfugpdohsiughsdopiughdsfoiguf.com"
    request_url = requests.get(url)
    print(request_url.status_code)
except ConnectionError:
    print("No exist")
```

Comment: Just tried it. I'm still getting a *exists* with the url *'www.isdfugpdohsiughsdopiughdsfoiguf.com*

Comment: @LLJ97 are you getting it with any non-existent hostname or just that one?

Comment: @khachik I'm getting it with every non-existent hostname. Just tried it in an online python compiler and I got an error.

Comment: @LLJ97 I fixed the code and edited the answer as well tried it and it worked. Mark it as +1 if it solved your problem.

Comment: @eddwinpaz sorry, it didn't work. Must be a problem with my pc or my network. But you're answer is still a good answer, so i'm gonna mark it anyways

Comment: @LLJ97 Please check you python version this is python3 maybe you are using python2.7